# 2D for loop array problem Why it is over length

Tags: java

```
            int x=10,y=10;
            char[][] gametable=new char[x][y];
            for(int i=0;i<gametable.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<gametable[i].length;i++)
                {
                    gametable[i][j]='.';
                    System.out.print(gametable[i][j]);
                }


                System.out.println(i);

            }
```

> the error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10
>           at test.main(test.java:9)
>   How to slove it?Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in second loop. You wrote `i++` instead of `j++`. Be careful next time!